# Getting the "InvocationTargetException" exception on the line driver=new ChromeDriver();

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, reflection, selenium-chromedriver, invocationtargetexception

I am opening the Chromebrowser, and getting the exeption `"InvocationTargetException"`. The code was running properly few days ago. Here is my code

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
driver=new ChromeDriver();
```

At the line `"driver=new ChromeDriver();"` I am getting the `"InvocationTargetException"` Exception

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### InvocationTargetException

[InvocationTargetException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html) is a checked exception that wraps an exception thrown by an invoked method or constructor. It is an extra level of abstraction by calling the method with reflection. The reflection layer wraps any exception in an `InvocationTargetException`. The "target exception" that is provided at construction time and accessed via the [`getTargetException()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/reflect/InvocationTargetException.html#getTargetException--) method is now known as the cause, and may be accessed via the [`Throwable.getCause()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/lang/Throwable.html#getCause--) method, as well as the aforementioned "legacy method."

### Solution

The best approach would be to **unwrap** the cause within the `InvocationTargetException` to get the the original exception.

```
try {

        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver","D:\\Automation\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver=new ChromeDriver();

} catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
        // the real cause
        e.getCause().printStackTrace();

} catch (Exception e) {
        // generic exception handling
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

### Best Practice

As per the best practices follow the below guidelines:

- Upgrade *ChromeDriver* to  current [ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6](https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/downloads) level.
- Keep *Chrome* version at *Chrome v74* levels. ([as per ChromeDriver v74.0.3729.6 release notes](https://chromedriver.storage.googleapis.com/74.0.3729.6/notes.txt))
- Execute your `@Test` as **non-root** user.
- Always invoke `driver.quit()` within `tearDown(){}` method to close & destroy the *WebDriver* and *Web Client* instances gracefully.

Comment: Thank you for your help, But got the solution, I just update my ChromeDriver and it works for me.